# What happened to the icons in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Icons are no longer mentioned in Bootstrap.
I wonder why that is?
I've looked in the documentation, and they're no longer mentioned.
Stack Overflow keeps asking me to up the quality of my post.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/css/#glyphicons

Comment: I think the reason why the site keeps asking you to up the quality of your post is because it's not even on topic here to begin with. Having posted literally **hundreds** of questions, it should be clear to you what that message is supposed to mean by now. That said, try posting an issue in the GitHub repo instead or something.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it invites speculative answers about the development of an off-site resource.

Comment: [**The icons are back!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222849/1420197)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extracted from the official documentation: "With the launch of Bootstrap 3, icons have been moved to a separate repository. This keeps the primary project as lean as possible, makes it easier for folks to swap icon libraries, and makes Glyphicons icon fonts more readily available to more people outside Bootstrap."

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/css/ (section glyphicons)

You can get the glyphicons [here](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Not right now. Glyphicons are availables inside Bootstrap 3.0.0.

Comment: [**The icons are back!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222849/1420197)

Answer (score 2):

They were separated to their own repository:
http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: [**The icons are back!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222849/1420197)