# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons CDN

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, twitter-bootstrap-3

> ## PAY ATTENTION!
>
> **The Bootstrap icons are back** after [**this pull request merge**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/9767).
>
> ---
>
> After going back and forth on this for the last couple weeks, I've decided to **restore the Glyphicons icon font to the main repo**. Given how prevalent icons are in UIs, it's probably a disservice to most folks to not include them (or some other icon font) in the same spot as the CSS and JS.
>
> With this update comes the following:
>
> - Restores documentation (on the Components page)
> - New variables, `@icon-font-path` and `@icon-font-name`, for flexibility in adding and removing icon fonts
> - Upgrades to latest Glyphicons (adding 40 new icons)
> - Removes the **old Glyphicons mention from the CSS page**
>
> We'll work on improving the customization of icon fonts in the future so swapping font libraries can be easier (which was the whole motivation for the original removal).

---

Which is the CDN url of the new version of Twitter Bootstrap Glyphicons?

From the Bootstrap 3 [they were moved into a separate repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901776/1420197), but I didn't find any CDN.

From the official documentation:

> With the launch of Bootstrap 3, icons have been moved to a separate repository. This keeps the primary project as lean as possible, makes it easier for folks to swap icon libraries, and makes Glyphicons icon fonts more readily available to more people outside Bootstrap.

On the [official website](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/) they don't provide a CDN url for icons.

Where can find it? I don't want to download the repository and include it into my project.

Comment: Boostrap CDN's Bootswatch theme css files doesn't include glyphicons, am I right ? File: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.0/amelia/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 160, accepted):

With the recent [release of bootstrap 3](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/), and the glyphicons being merged back to the main Bootstrap repo, [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) is now serving **the complete Bootstrap 3.0 css including Glyphicons**. The Bootstrap css reference is all you need to include: Glyphicons and its dependencies are on relative paths on the CDN site and are referenced in `bootstrap.min.css`.

In html:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In css:

```
 @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Here is a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FzPEj/)**.

**Note** that you have to use `.glyphicon` classes instead of `.icon`:

Example:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
```

**Also note** that you would still need to include `bootstrap.min.js` for usage of Bootstrap JavaScript components, see [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) for url.

---

**If you want to use the Glyphicons separately**, you can do that by directly referencing the Glyphicons css on [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

In html:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In css:

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

Since the `css` file already includes all the needed Glyphicons dependencies (which are in a relative path on the Bootstrap CDN site), adding the `css` file is all there is to do to start using Glyphicons.

Here is a working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DBu4u/4/) of the Glyphicons without Bootstrap.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Seems to be the correct answer, but the icons don't appear when switching to this url. Font awesome works good. The CSS file with the icon rules is loaded. Do I need anything more? Images?

Comment: @Johnツ The first class in the CSS file is a @font-face class that imports all the needed font files (including one `svg` image file), which are in a relative path on the *Bootstrap CDN* site. So you do not need anything more.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I will take a look later and will accept this answer ass soon my application work. Please edit your answer and add the content from comments to id. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just seen that `.icon` is no more used.

Comment: and don't use fonts from customized version until this issue will be resolved: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9925

Comment: This works for me:http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css

Comment: @ElGamed Thank you! Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Looks like the Glyphicons moved to //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: wow, thanks for the info. all those changes drive me crazy. Why don't they have better control on versioning? Upgrading bootstrap will make all icon lost!

Comment: This Net DNA CSS import still works!  Super lightweight compared to having all of bootstrap!

Comment: I must be missing something... but the glyphicons for 3.4 includes a few glyphicon-menu-* values that simply aren't in the 3.0.0 file, and everyone happily links to this broken file. I can't find anything that points to a non-broken file. What am I missing???

Answer (score 27):

An alternative would be to use [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for icons:

### Including Font-Awesome

Open [Font-Awesome on CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) and copy the CSS url of the latest version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<url>">
```

Or in CSS

```
@import url("<url>");
```

For example (note, the version will change):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
```

---

### Usage:

```
<i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
```

It contains [a lot of icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)!

Comment: After hours of trying to get the icons to work, linking to the font-awesome cdn solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Eenvincible Don't forget to use [the latest version](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/). The links from my answer are a little bit outdated.

Comment: The URL changed: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: And the font-awesome file contains a lot more icons. Nice.

Comment: Not including bootstrap's glyphicons but relying on fa instead will give problems for libraries that depend on bootstrap. E.g. Angular-ui-select will miss some icons

Comment: The URL is irrelevant again.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović: It's still perfectly relevant, but it might be out of date. CDNs tend not to keep old libraries around for very long. If you know what the new version is, go ahead and edit the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to have glyphicons icons without any additional css you can create a css file and put the code below and include it into main css file.

I have to create this extra file as link below was messing with my site styles too.

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Instead to using it directly I created a css file `bootstrap-glyphicons.css`

```css
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');src:url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');}.glyphicon{position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}
.glyphicon-asterisk:before{content:"\2a";}
.glyphicon-plus:before{content:"\2b";}
.glyphicon-euro:before{content:"\20ac";}
.glyphicon-minus:before{content:"\2212";}
.glyphicon-cloud:before{content:"\2601";}
.glyphicon-envelope:before{content:"\2709";}
.glyphicon-pencil:before{content:"\270f";}
.glyphicon-glass:before{content:"\e001";}
.glyphicon-music:before{content:"\e002";}
.glyphicon-search:before{content:"\e003";}
.glyphicon-heart:before{content:"\e005";}
.glyphicon-star:before{content:"\e006";}
.glyphicon-star-empty:before{content:"\e007";}
.glyphicon-user:before{content:"\e008";}
.glyphicon-film:before{content:"\e009";}
.glyphicon-th-large:before{content:"\e010";}
.glyphicon-th:before{content:"\e011";}
.glyphicon-th-list:before{content:"\e012";}
.glyphicon-ok:before{content:"\e013";}
.glyphicon-remove:before{content:"\e014";}
.glyphicon-zoom-in:before{content:"\e015";}
.glyphicon-zoom-out:before{content:"\e016";}
.glyphicon-off:before{content:"\e017";}
.glyphicon-signal:before{content:"\e018";}
.glyphicon-cog:before{content:"\e019";}
.glyphicon-trash:before{content:"\e020";}
.glyphicon-home:before{content:"\e021";}
.glyphicon-file:before{content:"\e022";}
.glyphicon-time:before{content:"\e023";}
.glyphicon-road:before{content:"\e024";}
.glyphicon-download-alt:before{content:"\e025";}
.glyphicon-download:before{content:"\e026";}
.glyphicon-upload:before{content:"\e027";}
.glyphicon-inbox:before{content:"\e028";}
.glyphicon-play-circle:before{content:"\e029";}
.glyphicon-repeat:before{content:"\e030";}
.glyphicon-refresh:before{content:"\e031";}
.glyphicon-list-alt:before{content:"\e032";}
.glyphicon-flag:before{content:"\e034";}
.glyphicon-headphones:before{content:"\e035";}
.glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036";}
.glyphicon-volume-down:before{content:"\e037";}
.glyphicon-volume-up:before{content:"\e038";}
.glyphicon-qrcode:before{content:"\e039";}
.glyphicon-barcode:before{content:"\e040";}
.glyphicon-tag:before{content:"\e041";}
.glyphicon-tags:before{content:"\e042";}
.glyphicon-book:before{content:"\e043";}
.glyphicon-print:before{content:"\e045";}
.glyphicon-font:before{content:"\e047";}
.glyphicon-bold:before{content:"\e048";}
.glyphicon-italic:before{content:"\e049";}
.glyphicon-text-height:before{content:"\e050";}
.glyphicon-text-width:before{content:"\e051";}
.glyphicon-align-left:before{content:"\e052";}
.glyphicon-align-center:before{content:"\e053";}
.glyphicon-align-right:before{content:"\e054";}
.glyphicon-align-justify:before{content:"\e055";}
.glyphicon-list:before{content:"\e056";}
.glyphicon-indent-left:before{content:"\e057";}
.glyphicon-indent-right:before{content:"\e058";}
.glyphicon-facetime-video:before{content:"\e059";}
.glyphicon-picture:before{content:"\e060";}
.glyphicon-map-marker:before{content:"\e062";}
.glyphicon-adjust:before{content:"\e063";}
.glyphicon-tint:before{content:"\e064";}
.glyphicon-edit:before{content:"\e065";}
.glyphicon-share:before{content:"\e066";}
.glyphicon-check:before{content:"\e067";}
.glyphicon-move:before{content:"\e068";}
.glyphicon-step-backward:before{content:"\e069";}
.glyphicon-fast-backward:before{content:"\e070";}
.glyphicon-backward:before{content:"\e071";}
.glyphicon-play:before{content:"\e072";}
.glyphicon-pause:before{content:"\e073";}
.glyphicon-stop:before{content:"\e074";}
.glyphicon-forward:before{content:"\e075";}
.glyphicon-fast-forward:before{content:"\e076";}
.glyphicon-step-forward:before{content:"\e077";}
.glyphicon-eject:before{content:"\e078";}
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{content:"\e079";}
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{content:"\e080";}
.glyphicon-plus-sign:before{content:"\e081";}
.glyphicon-minus-sign:before{content:"\e082";}
.glyphicon-remove-sign:before{content:"\e083";}
.glyphicon-ok-sign:before{content:"\e084";}
.glyphicon-question-sign:before{content:"\e085";}
.glyphicon-info-sign:before{content:"\e086";}
.glyphicon-screenshot:before{content:"\e087";}
.glyphicon-remove-circle:before{content:"\e088";}
.glyphicon-ok-circle:before{content:"\e089";}
.glyphicon-ban-circle:before{content:"\e090";}
.glyphicon-arrow-left:before{content:"\e091";}
.glyphicon-arrow-right:before{content:"\e092";}
.glyphicon-arrow-up:before{content:"\e093";}
.glyphicon-arrow-down:before{content:"\e094";}
.glyphicon-share-alt:before{content:"\e095";}
.glyphicon-resize-full:before{content:"\e096";}
.glyphicon-resize-small:before{content:"\e097";}
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign:before{content:"\e101";}
.glyphicon-gift:before{content:"\e102";}
.glyphicon-leaf:before{content:"\e103";}
.glyphicon-eye-open:before{content:"\e105";}
.glyphicon-eye-close:before{content:"\e106";}
.glyphicon-warning-sign:before{content:"\e107";}
.glyphicon-plane:before{content:"\e108";}
.glyphicon-random:before{content:"\e110";}
.glyphicon-comment:before{content:"\e111";}
.glyphicon-magnet:before{content:"\e112";}
.glyphicon-chevron-up:before{content:"\e113";}
.glyphicon-chevron-down:before{content:"\e114";}
.glyphicon-retweet:before{content:"\e115";}
.glyphicon-shopping-cart:before{content:"\e116";}
.glyphicon-folder-close:before{content:"\e117";}
.glyphicon-folder-open:before{content:"\e118";}
.glyphicon-resize-vertical:before{content:"\e119";}
.glyphicon-resize-horizontal:before{content:"\e120";}
.glyphicon-hdd:before{content:"\e121";}
.glyphicon-bullhorn:before{content:"\e122";}
.glyphicon-certificate:before{content:"\e124";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before{content:"\e125";}
.glyphicon-thumbs-down:before{content:"\e126";}
.glyphicon-hand-right:before{content:"\e127";}
.glyphicon-hand-left:before{content:"\e128";}
.glyphicon-hand-up:before{content:"\e129";}
.glyphicon-hand-down:before{content:"\e130";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right:before{content:"\e131";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left:before{content:"\e132";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up:before{content:"\e133";}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down:before{content:"\e134";}
.glyphicon-globe:before{content:"\e135";}
.glyphicon-tasks:before{content:"\e137";}
.glyphicon-filter:before{content:"\e138";}
.glyphicon-fullscreen:before{content:"\e140";}
.glyphicon-dashboard:before{content:"\e141";}
.glyphicon-heart-empty:before{content:"\e143";}
.glyphicon-link:before{content:"\e144";}
.glyphicon-phone:before{content:"\e145";}
.glyphicon-usd:before{content:"\e148";}
.glyphicon-gbp:before{content:"\e149";}
.glyphicon-sort:before{content:"\e150";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet:before{content:"\e151";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt:before{content:"\e152";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order:before{content:"\e153";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt:before{content:"\e154";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes:before{content:"\e155";}
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt:before{content:"\e156";}
.glyphicon-unchecked:before{content:"\e157";}
.glyphicon-expand:before{content:"\e158";}
.glyphicon-collapse-down:before{content:"\e159";}
.glyphicon-collapse-up:before{content:"\e160";}
.glyphicon-log-in:before{content:"\e161";}
.glyphicon-flash:before{content:"\e162";}
.glyphicon-log-out:before{content:"\e163";}
.glyphicon-new-window:before{content:"\e164";}
.glyphicon-record:before{content:"\e165";}
.glyphicon-save:before{content:"\e166";}
.glyphicon-open:before{content:"\e167";}
.glyphicon-saved:before{content:"\e168";}
.glyphicon-import:before{content:"\e169";}
.glyphicon-export:before{content:"\e170";}
.glyphicon-send:before{content:"\e171";}
.glyphicon-floppy-disk:before{content:"\e172";}
.glyphicon-floppy-saved:before{content:"\e173";}
.glyphicon-floppy-remove:before{content:"\e174";}
.glyphicon-floppy-save:before{content:"\e175";}
.glyphicon-floppy-open:before{content:"\e176";}
.glyphicon-credit-card:before{content:"\e177";}
.glyphicon-transfer:before{content:"\e178";}
.glyphicon-cutlery:before{content:"\e179";}
.glyphicon-header:before{content:"\e180";}
.glyphicon-compressed:before{content:"\e181";}
.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182";}
.glyphicon-phone-alt:before{content:"\e183";}
.glyphicon-tower:before{content:"\e184";}
.glyphicon-stats:before{content:"\e185";}
.glyphicon-sd-video:before{content:"\e186";}
.glyphicon-hd-video:before{content:"\e187";}
.glyphicon-subtitles:before{content:"\e188";}
.glyphicon-sound-stereo:before{content:"\e189";}
.glyphicon-sound-dolby:before{content:"\e190";}
.glyphicon-sound-5-1:before{content:"\e191";}
.glyphicon-sound-6-1:before{content:"\e192";}
.glyphicon-sound-7-1:before{content:"\e193";}
.glyphicon-copyright-mark:before{content:"\e194";}
.glyphicon-registration-mark:before{content:"\e195";}
.glyphicon-cloud-download:before{content:"\e197";}
.glyphicon-cloud-upload:before{content:"\e198";}
.glyphicon-tree-conifer:before{content:"\e199";}
.glyphicon-tree-deciduous:before{content:"\e200";}
.glyphicon-briefcase:before{content:"\1f4bc";}
.glyphicon-calendar:before{content:"\1f4c5";}
.glyphicon-pushpin:before{content:"\1f4cc";}
.glyphicon-paperclip:before{content:"\1f4ce";}
.glyphicon-camera:before{content:"\1f4f7";}
.glyphicon-lock:before{content:"\1f512";}
.glyphicon-bell:before{content:"\1f514";}
.glyphicon-bookmark:before{content:"\1f516";}
.glyphicon-fire:before{content:"\1f525";}
.glyphicon-wrench:before{content:"\1f527";}
```

And imported the created css file into my main css file which enable me to just import the glyphicons only. Hope this help

```
@import url("bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

Comment: Yeah the boostrap include has unwanted styles beyond the icons.  Your method works better for me, but I just needed to change "http" to "https" in the font-face src definitions for secure SSL pages and then it works great without affecting margins, fonts, etc.

Comment: @OGSean Thanks for bringing out the SSL implementation here.

Answer (score 3):

Although Bootstrap CDN restored glyphicons to bootstrap.min.css, Bootstrap CDN's Bootswatch css files doesn't include glyphicons.

For example Amelia theme: http://bootswatch.com/amelia/

Default Amelia has glyphicons in this file: http://bootswatch.com/amelia/bootstrap.min.css

But Bootstrap CDN's css file doesn't include glyphicons: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.0/amelia/bootstrap.min.css

So as @edsioufi mentioned, you should include you should include glphicons css, if you use Bootswatch files from the bootstrap CDN. File: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css

Comment: Also the customizer at bootstrap generates invalid font files sometimes. A separate download of font files helped me get back my icons. Its a bootstrap package bug sometimes.

Comment: trante: your information is incorrect. If you check your links you will find that  the Bootstrap CDN for the bootswatch theme(s) does include glyphicons.