# Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am migrating from bootstrap 2.3 to bootstrap 3 and everything works well. But when I tried to add some icons, the icon font doesn't displayed properly. I tried to look over here http://bootply.com/61521 and only '.glyphicon-envelope' was being displayed properly. Others have displayed like 'E001' and so on.

How can I be able to solve this problem?

For other browsers, glyphicons are displayed properly, only firefox was unables to display it properly.

Comment: The glyphicons CSS is automatically included on Bootply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31522226/1286942

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons are not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-are-not-working)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, my problem was not answered by the above. I had the fonts folder at the same location as the bootstrap css and js folders (eg /theme/bootstrap3/..), but it was looking for the font folder in the root (eg /fonts/glyph.. .woff)

The solution for me was to set the @icon-font-path variable to the correct relative path:

Eg @icon-font-path:   "fonts/";

Comment: bootstrap.min.css shouldn't be looking for the font files in the document root (that would break many applications) but rather in ../fonts, relative to itself: `url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)` So don't change the original directory structure (fonts/, css/, js/).

Comment: hello @brad, I am facing the same issue..my files is inside css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css  the icons are displaying chinese chracters on android device and some other icons are displayed for iOS. what will the change shall to do for working ?

Comment: where to add relative path and where is font file linked as now ?

Answer (score 80):

Did you choose the customized version of Bootstrap? There is an issue that the font files included in the customized package are broken (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9925). If you do not want to use the CDN, you have to download them manually and replace your own fonts with the downloaded ones:

https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

After that try a strong reload (CTRL + F5), hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried this many times but it's not fixing it for me. Chrome dev tools shows a 301 permanent redirect error, but I can't figure out how to fix it!

Comment: I didn't customise my download and I still had this problem. Downloading the files from the CDN as suggested fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem on BS 3.3.2 installed via bower.  Font files are loading and are identical to non-custom zip download straight from getbootstrap.com

Comment: Only worked when I replaced the ../fonts/... urls in the bootstrap.min.css file with the CDN, and not when I downloaded and replaced the files.

Answer (score 40):

the icons and the css are now seperated out from bootstrap.  here is a fiddle that is from another stackoverflow answer

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aQrPd/1/

[Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222849/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-cdn)

Comment: I don't want to use CDN cause I'm working offline almost of the time.

Comment: @ivan, you can just d/l the css to your server instead of using the cdn.  just replace the cdn url with your own url of course.

Comment: I have tried it already but never works. Using the CDN works but when I tried to replace it with my own URL where the css file is located, it doesn't work. Only the 'glyphicon-envelope' is being displayed properly. -_- I guess I'm just missing something.

Comment: @iSa You have to download the resources too (everything inside `url`, mainly font files), the CSS alone isn't gonna cut it.

Comment: Yes, I know. Everything works fine with other browsers but not with Mozilla Firefox 21.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason Glyphicons weren't included in my Bootstrap template... adding this worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the fix that worked for me. Firefox has a file origin policy that causes this. To fix do the following steps:

1. open about:config in firefox
2. Find security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy property and change it from ‘true’ to ‘false.’
3. Voial! you are good to go!

Details:
http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/firefoxs_file_uri_origin_policy_and_web_fonts

You will only see this issue when accessing a file using file:/// protocol

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem using a local apache server. This solved my problem:

http://www.ifusio.com/blog/firefox-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons

For Amazon s3 you need to edit your CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Could you share what have you done in your CORS to have fonts working with Amazon S3? I'm hunting info all over the web about this fonts issue with amazon s3

Comment: hi Cassiano, i added my configuration. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I try to install the glyphicons fonts by the "oficial" way, with the zip file. I could not do it.

This is my step-by-step solution:

1. Go to the web page of Bootstrap and then to the "Components"
   section.
2. Open the browser console. In Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+C.
3. In section Resources, inside Frames/getbootstrap.com/Fonts you will
   find the font that actually is running the glyphicons. It's
   recommended to use the private mode to evade cache.
4. With URL of
   the font file (right-click on the file showed on resources list),
   copy it in a new tab, and press ENTER. This will download the font
   file.
5. Copy another time the URL in a tab and change the font
   extension to eot, ttf, svg or woff, ass you like.

However, for a more easy acces, this is the link of the woff file.

http://getbootstrap.com/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Answer (score 3):

I ended up switching to Font-Awesome Icons. They are just as good if not better, and all you need to do is link in the font, happy days.

Answer (score 2):

make sure the name of the folder that contains the font name is "fonts" not "font"

Answer (score 1):

you can use  tag like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
```

Comment: Fa icons cannot be used this way. Please be clear in answer. Please don't answer for sake of answer.

Comment: Unrelated. The answer is about glyphicons, not about fa-icons. If you wanted to mention about the <i> tag, be clear and in the example use it with a glyphicon.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case :

For example, I just tryed `<span class="icones glyphicon glyphicon-pen">`
and after one hour i realized that this icon was not included in the bootstrap pack !! While the enveloppe icon was working fine..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there are some issues with the customizer.

I was having troubles with the glyphicons not showing either, as well as issues with the navbar layout.

I used the suggestion and uploaded the fonts from the full zip/overwrote the ones from the customized version and that fixed the icons issues.

I also pulled in the CDN CSS and javascript instead of my local copy from the CDN. This fixed my navbar issues.

So I recommend until you get the hang of Bootstrap, not to use the customized version since you might get some frustrating, unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

For me placing my **fonts**  folder as per location specified in bootstrap.css solved the problem

Mostly its  **fonts**  folder should be in parent directory of bootstrap.css file .

I faced this problem , and researching  many answers , if anyone still in 2015 faces this problem then its either a CSS problem , or location mismatch for files .

The bug has already been solved  by bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation supporting the above answers.

> Changing the icon font location
> Bootstrap assumes icon font files will be located in the ../fonts/ directory, relative to the compiled CSS files. Moving or renaming those font files means updating the CSS in one of three ways:
>
> Change the @icon-font-path and/or @icon-font-name variables in the source Less files.
> Utilize the relative URLs option provided by the Less compiler.
> Change the url() paths in the compiled CSS.
> Use whatever option best suits your specific development setup.

Other than this one mistake the new users would do is, after downloading the bootstrap zip from the official website. They would tend to skip the fonts folder for copying in their dev setup. **So missing fonts folder can also lead to this problem**

Answer (score -1):

1. Try using CDN
2. Try setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP Header