# Twitter Bootstrap 3 icon displaying a square

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Font files are in the right place and html code is with charset utf-8.

Thats the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta chaset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste icone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

and thats the file structure:

```
-css
   *bootstrap.min.css
-fonts
    *all font files here
*index.html
```

The strange is that when i look on debug all font files are loaded correctly

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: check in different browsers, font files are loading correctly or not, also make sure the mime type is set accordingly.

Comment: Chrome is displaying a square and FF is displaying a strange code.

Comment: I was taking over a code base for someone and the issue for me was that they were using <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> instead of using span

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Guys the issue was font files were corrupteds, the weird is that I've tried download bootstrap 3 times from differents devices and all of then I had the same issue.
The most strange is that I research a lot for days and apparently nobody had the same issue.
So.. thats it!

Comment: I am having the same issue. how did you get the correct files finally? I have also downloaded it many times, and it seems that all of them is "corrupted".....

Comment: @Brian I had the same issue, I wget the files from the links in there:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly the md5sum look allright according to the answer above

Comment: I am running into this as well, however it seems to only be an issue in Chrome. Of all things, it works fine in IE.

Answer (score 16):

Try re-downloading the fonts, may be corrupt.

Check the MD5

```
MD5 (glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot) = 2469ccfe446daa49d5c1446732d1436d
MD5 (glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg) = 3b31e1de93290779334c84c9b07c6eed
MD5 (glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) = aa9c7490c2fd52cb96c729753cc4f2d5
MD5 (glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) = 7c4cbe928205c888831ba76548563ca3
```

Answer (score 8):

in your bootstrap.css try to add !important in .glyphicon font-family..

```
.glyphicon {
   font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
   // more css comes along here
}
```

other css might cause conflict to change the glyphicons font-family.

Comment: This worked for me, with Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

In bootstrap.css this is the link to the fonts. (Line 2386 or just search for face)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

**Removing the '..' before each link worked for me**

e.g

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Although this max fix the issue, editing the source file is bad practice and can cause issues later when you need to update bootstrap. Probably another answer is preferable

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried removing the font for a icon on tb3 site and it displays as a square. 
Make sure you have the font folder in the same level as your css folder, provided font folder has all the files.

the structure should be:

```
- css
  -bootstrap-theme.css
  -bootstrap-theme.min.css
  -bootstrap.css
  -bootstrap.min.css

-fonts
  -glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
  -glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
  -glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
  -glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

css code: `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'`

Comment: theres a folder css and a folder fonts. I tried put font files inside css folder together css files but still displaying a square

Comment: @DanielFaria check my answer again.

Comment: structure is exactly like that

Comment: @DanielFaria then make sure you don't have any console errors like may be any css, font file is not found. what browser are u using? and hav u tried testing in any other browser?

Comment: @DanielFaria hey what's the issue? have you tried in any other browser?

Answer (score 1):

[See Stijn answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working)

> Note to readers: be sure to read [@user2261073's
>   comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working/18369117#comment26972465_18369117)
>   and [@Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474869/247702)
>   concerning a bug in the customizer. It's likely the cause of your
>   problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
src: font-url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
```

instead of

```
src: url("../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
```

changed, and works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a permission problem. The fonts didnt have the appropriate permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'font' directory is available in your root folder, as most of the bootstrap CSS directs to glyphicon fonts which must be clubbed in some folder within the root folder or home folder directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because you have downloaded the free version of Glyphicons, which *only* includes bacic and social icons. If you use the free version, some icons are simply not there, and will render the square.

I switched to using a CDN and linking in my head and everything worked!

CDN: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 0):

My fonts folder was simply in the wrong directory, it had to go one level up.

Answer (score -3):

I Have this problem and  After very search :

1. glyph-icons is free just for use CDN.
2. instead of use glyph-icons you can use Awesome icons that free.
   more information in http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/get-started/