# @fontface css font path does not seem to work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a directory called `project` and in it i have the directories `html`,`assets` and `javascript`.The assets `directory` has the directories `fonts` and `css`.The `css` directory has a css file called `typography.css`.The fonts directory has all the fonts i am using.

Inside the `html` directory i have a file `typography.html`. To use the fonts i am using this code inside `typography.css` which is correctly linked/referenced in my html file.However this code inside `typography.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "LatoLight";
    src: url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.woff') format("woff"), url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.svg') format("svg");
    }
    h1{ font-family: LatoLight !important; }
```

does not produce the desired result.I am using twitter bootstrap 3.Why is this not working?.

Comment: Have you tried putting the font files directly in the css folder and linking it there to see if there is any other issues other than the possible directory issue?

Comment: Yes,i have done that too and that fails too.However when i use inline style inside my typography.html file and add all the fonts inside the html directly,voila it works but i need the fonts to be in the fonts directory.

Comment: what browser you using?

Comment: I am using Firefox 23.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoLight';
    src: url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.eot') format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.woff') format("woff"), 
         url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), 
         url('../fonts/lato-light-webfont.svg') format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've switched double quotes to single. It MIGHT make a difference but i am not sure.

otherwise this might help [Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly) i know it's glyphicons but firefox might just be having issues regarding other fonts.

Comment: The problem was `file origin policy` issue which was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068467/2420583 in the question you linked.After setting this property `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to false it now works.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: This is very nice.  With this approach you can override the original paths that bootstrap provides within your custom .less file and point the font files to wherever.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be as simple as putting quotes around the font you want when you reference it.

```
h1{ font-family: "LatoLight" !important; }
```