# Bootstrap flat-ui glyphs not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm using bootstrap with flat-ui. Glyphs is displaying correctly if bootstrap and flat-ui files are on the same directory as the site. But when I transfer these files to a different directory and just point the files there from the site (with a different directory), the glyphs are just displaying "E024".

site directory:
/var/www/html/tn

bootstrap/flat-ui directory:
/var/www/html/fui

I have read this [Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)

Actually the glyphs are displaying correctly on other browsers other than firefox in win7.

but that didn't help. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with Firefox.  In my case, I was loading a bootstrap 3 based HTML5 web application from the local file system, not from a web server.  Apparently Firefox has security settings with this and local fonts - see this other answer:

[CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

In short, for me I was able to fix this in Firefox by changing the preference security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false.