# Bootstrap v3.0.0 visual studio 2013 MVC - Missing icons(glyphicon)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Iam visual studio 2013 MVC and I use the built in bootstrap, but Iam missing a lot of these Icons.

http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=mlse9u&s=8#.UyGxe4V9LXI

How can I add them or how can i fix that problem ?

Ty for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is relevant of your problem, it's about custom bootstrap with glyphicon broken.

[Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)

Comment: hi, that solved my problem: @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ty for you help :)