# calling twitter bootstrap style css in liferay portal 6.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay, liferay-6

I'm working with liferay 6.2 and I would like to apply css style on a button (I want to use twitter bootstrap, as liferay provides bootstrap for ui development).
please help.

Comment: What did you try already? What doesn't work? What works? How do you generate your button? Give code

Comment: I wanted to use Glyphicons. I tryed 
`<li>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon-class">glyphicon glyphicon-plus</span>
        </li>` 
but it didn't work. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly add below code into your CSS file:

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
```

Related Question: [Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)