# Bootstrap doesn't show all glyphicon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have some problem with the bootstrap glyphicon.

I'm using many glyphocon on my project at the moment, but I can't use all of them.

I'll try to explain myself better.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large text-primary"></span>
```

This on, work fine on my website, but:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses text-primary"></span>
```

this one not.

I tryed to download a clean bootstrap and and I just take the font folder and replaced the file in my project. But nothing changed.

I have this problem with some random glyphicon, not with all of them.

I really have no idea why :/

P.s. I already tryed also this: [Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)

Comment: `glyphicon-sunglasses` is new in glyphicons 1.9. Do you have the right version of glyphicons?

Comment: Just changing the font is not enougth. You must also update the css file, because the `glyphicon-sunglasses` class is needed to display the glyphicon.

Comment: Okkei probably I'm dumb, but where I have to update it? 
In bootstrap.css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This glyphicon is new so you need the new font. But you also need to add the correct class as well. Just changing the font-file will not add it. Replace your `bootstrap.css` file or add this to your existing file:

```
.glyphicon-sunglasses:before {
  content: "\e240";
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks, and sorry for the dumb question to all he people here ;)

Comment: @ZenoTrevisan it's not a dumb question at all. We all have a different way of learning