# Relative URL in @font-face source doesn't work

Tags: html, css, font-face, src

I downloaded Delicious-Roman font and I want to use it in my CSS page. It doesn't seem to work with relative URL, but when i placed it in same folder as my CSS page, it worked! My folders look like this:

```
-Project
   -Fonts
       -Delicious-Roman.otf
   -Folder
       -Project.html
       -ProjectStyle.css
```

So I did this:

```
@font-face{
   font-family: Delicious;
   src: url(../Fonts/Delicious-Roman.otf);
}
div{
   font-family: Delicious;
}
```

But it doesn't work. When i put `Delicious-Roman.otf` in `Folder` and do this:

```
 @font-face{
   font-family: Delicious;
   src: url(Delicious-Roman.otf);
}
div{
   font-family: Delicious;
}
```

its all good and it works. Also I've seen people put `format(otf);` next to the `src`, but i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably testing this in Firefox. Try Chrome and it will work. For the Firefox fix, see: [Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly/19068467#19068467)

Comment: I was able to make it work on my machine with the exact same font. Yes on Chrome, not on Firefox. Did you also make sure that the capitalization matches on your folder/file names? I use lowercase on everything to avoid that problem.

Comment: Woops, sorry again. It works in chrome. I had a typo. Fix works too! Thanks!