# glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 not loading 404 error

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3, http-status-code-404

I have tried a lot and have seen so many answers but none is helping me out here.
I am not sure why the glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2  not able to load even i have latest bootstrap version.

[Bootstrap 3 unable to display glyphicon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)

Directory Structure

[image]

Error

[image]

@font-face rule in css

```
   @font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: What are your @font-face rules? Can you see your fonts if you just straight up type their URL in the browser to download them? Also note that WOFF2 [isn't very widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2) (as opposed to .WOFF, which is supported by [pretty much everything](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff))

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No I am not able download them if i type their URL in browser and I have added the font-face rule it is exactly as same as bootstrap provided no alteration on css have been made.I am not able to recognize why this happens

Comment: this is way too many font versions. just the WOFF will do, with .eot if you absolutely must support ancient IE versions. With that said, can you add which locations you tried in the browser to see if your files download? e.g. when the server's running and you try localhost/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, what's the response? If you put a test.html in that dir, can you get to that file or is it also nonexistent, if you put it one dir up, can you get to it, etc

Answer (score 2):

Assign mime type values:

**mimeMap:**

- fileExtension=".woff"
- mimeType="application/font-woff"
- fileExtension=".woff2"
- mimeType="application/font-woff"

Answer (score 1):

I modified file: (applicationhost.config) :: Add mimeMap

Go to `%UserProfile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

Find

```xml
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
```

Change or Add

```xml
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Font refernce such as Bootstrap are usually relative:
`src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)`

So create two folders like this

`bootstrap
    bootstrap.min.css
    bootstrap.min.js
fonts
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`

So the css can be reference as:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the following elements to your **web.xml**, immediately within the **<web-app>** tag:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>.woff</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>.woff2</extension>
    <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```