# Button with glyphicon is not working in mozilla firefox?

Tags: php, html, mozilla

This code is working on other browser except in Mozilla Firefox

```
<button type="button">
    <a href="edit_teacher.php?edit=<?php echo $row['teach_id']; ?>">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="font-size: 20px; color: green;">
       </span>
   </a>
</button>
```

Comment: For future reference, http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting; can't see current code but sounds like a css/html issue; not PHP issue.

Comment: just look at to these solutions [your problem solved here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  it may work.

```
.glyphicon {
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" !important;
}
```