# Where is glyphicons in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Currently i just downloaded Bootstrap 3 via [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) tab using some custom colors and i got 2 files, one for css and one for JS.

The problem is compiled css doesn't contains any "glyphicon" value. [I was read](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342) as of bootstrap 3 glyphicons with fonts moved to separate repository.

- This page produces 404: http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/
- Also produces 404 not found: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons

I also tried to manually download glyphicons from http://glyphicons.com (Free one) but all icons are PNG format and there is no FONT file for that.

What is the proper way of using "external but partially free glyphicons for bootstrap" fonts with my custom bootstrap.css file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18225474/703717

Comment: This is old and has been corrected.