# glyphicons are not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason the icons are not loading for the images when i use twitter bootstrap 2.3.2. I have the default structure
css/
img/
js/

Everything else works and i have also tried to add a simple icon like `<span class="icon icon-ok">OK</span>` and that also works

Can anyone see whats wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fixed layout example with Twitter Bootstrap</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <!-- Bootstrap -->  
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<form class="form-horizontal">

        <fieldset>
          <legend>Create a new question</legend>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="questionTitle">Title</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="questionTitle">              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="questionText">Question</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="questionText" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="questionTypes">What type of answer are your looking for?</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> Multiple choice  
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjus"></span> Yes/No  
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-width"></span> Text input  
            </button>
          </div>                   
          <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222849/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-cdn?rq=1). Maybe it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using  tag like this:

```
<i class="icon-star icon-white"></i>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

EDIT: Looks like you may be using v3.0.0 - Did you try using the glyphicons without the additional classes you've added? Just the standard classes:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
```

If that loads, then it may have something to do with `glyphicon-text-width` and `glyphicon-adjus` (adjus is spelled wrong maybe?)

Comment: I tought that i was using 2.3.2 but it was apperently v3 and after that it was straight forward. Thank you for the hint