# Local bootstrap 3.1 glyphicons not loading in Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, glyphicons

I'm creating a local HTML UI font icons from bootstrap don't load in Firefox, they do in Chrome and IE.

Not working/does not apply:
https://superuser.com/questions/446001/firefox-cannot-render-icons-from-font-awesome-webfont-set

[glyphicons are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420832/glyphicons-are-not-loading)

[Bootstrap 3 cdn glyphicons not loading in firefox only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060994/bootstrap-3-cdn-glyphicons-not-loading-in-firefox-only)

[Glyphicons from bootstrap 3 not rendering on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221895/glyphicons-from-bootstrap-3-not-rendering-on-firefox)

https://github.com/MaxCDN/bootstrap-cdn/issues/196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is apparently https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

What works for me is:

"If you have a page at file:////pages/mypage.html, then you can only load fonts located in file:////pages or below. So, for example, if the fonts are in file:////fonts, they won't load, but if they are in file:///pages/fonts, then they should work. At least, that's how it seems to work for me."
posted by freixas @ 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956597

So basically I put my resources dir (contains scripts, images etc) in the root directory where I have the web pages.