# Boostrap glyphicon icons- not showing correctly in firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am using bootsrap plugin version - bootstrap-3.2.0

I tried to display the icons. its working well in chrome browser but its not good in firefox browser.
I used the following code bellow:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="dist/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Glyphicon in a H1 tag -->
    <h1>Hello, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
     !</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I attached the screen shot for both browser.
1.Chrome browser screen shot its looks good.
[image]

2. Firefox browser screen shot.
   [image]

Comment: [This sounds like it could be the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680700/local-bootstrap-3-1-glyphicons-not-loading-in-firefox)

Comment: At the address below explains why:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085942/boootstrap-glyphicons-firefox-issues][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085942/boootstrap-glyphicons-firefox-issues