# Bootstrap 3.0.0 glyphicon-earphone not loading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have replaced the glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff/eot/svg/ttf files with the latest, but I still can't get the glyphicon-earphone to work. I get a thin rectangle with an open bottom instead. Same goes for glyphicon-phone-alt, but most others work perfectly.

I tried to reproduce the issue on Bootply.com, but it works as expected there. Regardless, here is the link and code.

http://bootply.com/76942

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="contact_phone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cell">Cell</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell" id="contact_cell">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this a bug in Bootstrap 3.0.0? If so - I guess the Bootply site has applied a 'patch/fix' for 3.0.0?

Comment: No, definitely not a bug. Make sure you are including the Glyphicons correctly on your site. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222849/2274357). Try to use the CDN on your site. If it works, you would have to adjust your local includes if you insist on having the files on your server.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it. The glyphicon files on Github are newer than what downloads from GetBootstrap.com. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reasons can be change in default bootstrap folders hierarchy. Fonts and the Bootstrap folders should be at the same level.
See a similar question: [Bootstrap loading wrong glyphicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583025/bootstrap-loading-wrong-glyphicon)