# How to make the Twitter Bootstrap Glyphicons work with Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are a lot of questions in stackoverflow. But none of them has solved my problem.

Especially I checked this [Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222849/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-cdn/18225474#18225474)

But it didn't work for me.

My website http://mywebsite.com doesn't show icons. I added everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the Glyphicon font-family. You must include Bootstrap's css file first before including yours.

Comment: I moved my custom css after bootstrap's css. Nothing changed.

Comment: You are also overriding the glyphicon class, you must change html * to just html in your custom.css file.

Comment: Works like a charm. But I will need your 1 more help. Since I will remove this, I gotta put this to somewhere so I have wrapper called 'wrap', How I will force to set the font to 'Open Sans' as I did with HTML

Comment: The font is Open Sans, you are essentially setting every font besides the ones that are explicitly set to Open Sans.

Comment: I want to force it since I use different CSS snipets and they may have different font. Forcing solves my problem. I am lazy about it. How will I force it without having problems with glyphicon.

Comment: You would just do #wrap { font-family: 'Open Sans' sans-serif; }

Comment: But it won't override any other fonts that defined under wrap. Would putting '!important' solve my problem?

Comment: @SNaRe Those fonts are already defined in the respective CSS class, you could just do `#wrap * { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }` then do `#wrap glyphicon { font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove this style:

```
html * {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

from `custom.css` which is located at:

```
http://serhat.gen.tr/wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-master/css/custom.css
```

Comment: What can I do about it?

Comment: Go to that file location and search for the style above, then remove it or just keep `html` instead of `html *`

Comment: I want to force it since I use different CSS snipets and they may have different font. Forcing solves my problem. I am lazy about it. How will I force it without having problems with glyphicon. –