# Bootstrap - Only shows two glyphicons in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I imported the css/js/font of bootstrap3 in my sample html page. But in the case of glyphicons. It shows only two Glyphicon properly (glyphicon-asterisk, glyphicon-plus). All others are not showing. So i open the glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf file and it shows only two symbols (glyphicon-asterisk, glyphicon-plus) with some texts. May be this becomes the problem. How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try including this link

It will show all glyphs.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222849/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-cdn) for  CDN

Comment: Interesting, Got the icons. But it also results some impacts in input text files, which is there is a shadow cames in all text fields.

Comment: Dont know what are you talking about!

Comment: Sorry my mistake,  the problem is due the css files are not in proper location that's why this happens